How to get the statement that triggered a trigger function when it is called as part of multi-statement query or function in PL/pgSQL?
I have an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger on a view. Its trigger function calls current_query(). When inserting something directly into this view, everything works fine.
But when something is inserted into this view by a "multi-statement query" or some other function/code-block, current_query() returns the whole top-level query, instead of just the single INSERT statement.
To clarify, here is a full minimum reproducible example:
Setup:
SET client_min_messages TO NOTICE;

CREATE TABLE usr (
    id bigint NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    first_name TEXT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT usr_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE VIEW usr_view AS
  SELECT id, first_name
  FROM usr;


CREATE FUNCTION on_insert_view() RETURNS TRIGGER
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
    current_query text;
BEGIN
    SELECT CURRENT_QUERY()
    INTO current_query;

    RAISE NOTICE 'current_query: %', current_query;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER on_insert_view INSTEAD OF INSERT ON usr_view FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION on_insert_view();

Query 1 (single statement):
INSERT INTO usr_view (first_name) VALUES ('John');

Returns:
NOTICE:  current_query: INSERT INTO usr_view (first_name) VALUES ('John');

Query 2 (multi-statement query):
INSERT INTO usr_view (first_name) VALUES ('John');
INSERT INTO usr_view (first_name) VALUES ('Bob');

Returns:
NOTICE:  current_query: INSERT INTO usr_view (first_name) VALUES ('John');
INSERT INTO usr_view (first_name) VALUES ('Bob');
NOTICE:  current_query: INSERT INTO usr_view (first_name) VALUES ('John');
INSERT INTO usr_view (first_name) VALUES ('Bob');
INSERT 0 1

Query 3 (anonymous code block):
DO $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO usr_view (first_name) VALUES ('John');
END;
$$;

Returns:
NOTICE:  current_query: DO $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO usr_view (first_name) VALUES ('John');
END;
$$;

My expectation was that current_query() would return the same thing as it returns for Query 1 for all the three queries listed above.
Unfortunately it does not... So my question is, if there is a way to get the statement that actually triggers the trigger function, as opposed to getting the top-level query that this statement is a part of?

The manual is pretty clear about this: Returns the text of the currently executing query, as submitted by the client (which might contain more than one statement)..

What client are you using? psql responds with 'John' then 'Bob', not 'John' twice like you showed. Also, I think you might be confusing multi-statement query with multiple queries. This is multi-statement: with cte as (insert into usr_view(first_name) values ('John') returning id) delete from usr_view where id not in (select id from cte); The two inserts you showed are just multiple queries, which all clients execute one by one. The do block does count like multi-statement query.

@FrankHeikens Yes, I have read that description of current_query() in the manual. My point is that I'm surprised that that is the behavior. It seems to me like returning the statement responsible for triggering the trigger function is more valuable (and more intuitive?) most of the time.

@Zegarek I'm using PgAdmin's "Query tool". For "Query 2", each INSERT returns both insert statements.
Thank you for pointing that out! What I meant with multi-statement is that when I execute each query separately I get the same output as for "Query 1", but when I select both statements and then run them together I get the output as shown for "Query 2". I hope that that makes sense :)

A single query can result in many many SQL statements and even more under-the-hood validations. In parallel. Maybe you can do something with the different log levels? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-SEVERITY-LEVELS

@FrankHeikens Thank you for that suggestion! Do I understand you correctly that it's possible to access logs from a trigger function? And that in those logs I might be able to find the statement responsible for triggering the trigger function?

No, but you can emit specific log messages from specific parts/statements in your multi-statement query. If what you do is difficult to trace based on the trigger variables, this idea might be a simple method to just mark those statements or emit messages from them.


a way to get the statement that actually triggers the trigger function, as opposed to getting the top-level query that this statement is a part of?

You'll need to consult special trigger variables TG_OP and TG_TABLE_NAME and correlate that with the ouput of current_query().

I think your understanding of multi-statement query might be off. The doc says:

current_query () → text
Returns the text of the currently executing query, as submitted by the client (which might contain more than one statement).

From what you showed, not one of the examples contains more than one statement. The do block could. Using CTEs could be another example:
with cte1 as (insert into usr_view(first_name) 
              values ('John') 
              returning id) 
,    cte2 as (delete from usr_view 
              where id not in (select id 
                               from cte1) )
insert into usr_view(first_name) 
values ('Bob');

The insert is one statement, the delete is another, then the last, outermost insert is yet another, third statement, and they all come in a single query. What you did is divide them into separate, single-statement queries:
INSERT INTO usr_view (first_name) VALUES ('John');
INSERT INTO usr_view (first_name) VALUES ('Bob');

And I believe your client, like mine, responded with a notice for the first one first, then another notice for the second one, separately. After all, the function offers to report the entire currently processed query, even if there are multiple statements in it. It does not promise to report multiple queries that the client sent together.
Multiple statements can make up a single query but multiple queries are just multiple queries - sometimes called a pipeline.
Your example of the do anonymous procedural code block is also single-statement but if you did add some more, current_query() would show the whole thing:
DO $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO usr_view (first_name) VALUES ('John'); 
    UPDATE usr_view SET first_name=first_name||' UPDATED';
END;
$$;


NOTICE:  current_query: DO $$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO usr_view (first_name) VALUES ('John'); 
   UPDATE usr_view SET first_name=first_name||' UPDATED';
   UPDATE another_thing SET a=1;
END;
$$;



DO


And if the trigger fired on the first one, TG_TABLE_NAME would be usr_view and TG_OP would show INSERT, pointing you to the statement responsible.

Thank you for your answer and your clarifications! If I understand your answer correctly, there is no way to get the specific statement that triggered an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger? So my best bet would be to use the TG_TABLE_NAME and TG_OP params to "extract" the statement from the result of calling current_query() right? The one downside I see with this, is that if there are multiple inserts on the same view, I can no longer with certainty select the exact statement responsible for calling the trigger...

You can, based on the value of the primary key and other fields in the new record you can inspect inside the trigger - you can look at what is being inserted and trace that back to the particular insert responsible. There might be some kind of a "current_statement()" implementation if you look around some lower level debugging and development tools and extensions for Postgres, but if you find one, I'd expect it to require superuser, significantly slow everything down and/or open a prod system to security threats, or all of the above.

Oh I wish the current_statement() function would exist... Yeah looking at NEW could work if the values to be inserted are known at the time of the query being sent. In our case, it might happen that these values come from a loop, in which case current_query() shows the raw query with the variable names provided by the loop and not the actual values... Thanks for your help anyway! :)
